# htpasswd file and NGINX

Tags: nginx, .htpasswd

The site is using php 5.6.40 FPM by NGINX on Centos 7.8.2033 - Plesk Onyx 17.8.11

- The site is hosted on https://boutique.domaine.fr
- The admin console can be accessed through : https://https://boutique.domaine.fr/admin
- I used by the past Apache and `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` were fine.

I absolutely need to protect this admin area by an existing `.htpasswd`
I do not want to use SSH as I am not used to it.

I tried:

```
location ^~ /admin { 
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/vhosts/domaine.fr/boutique/admin/.htpasswd;
}
```

But this does not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works, it denies the other connections unless they are properly authenticated.

```
location ^~ /admin { 
deny all;
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /var/www/vhosts/domaine.fr/boutique/admin/.htpasswd;
}
```

If it doesn't work you also have the option to restrict the directory by IP, which is simpler and provides security.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/#combining-basic-authentication-with-access-restriction-by-ip-address

Comment: Hi Luis, thank you so much. I'll try your trick and let you know ;-)